# Neuropharmacology and Simulation

Tags: neuroscience, computational-modeling, neurology

I've been wondering whether neural simulations have had applications in (cognitive)neuropharmacological research already. One always reads about the *promise* of the technology in helping us cure various brain disorders, but I only know of relatively theoretical (general) models thereof derived from / supported by simulation. Has anyone actually attempted to identify drug targets computationally?

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are asking for but I found this paper  http://m.jn.physiology.org/content/99/5/2703 However an application in vivo is still unclear as stated by the authors.

Comment: On second thought it still a theoretical model with promise of application so maybe I am not particularly helpful.

Comment: No, that's exactly the type of work I was looking for!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suitable for Biology.SE. Additionally, it is too broad and unclear.